# Iterating through a sub-section of result resource in PHP-MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

In my program I launch an SQL query and get back a result resource.  I then iterate through the rows of this result resource using the mysql_fetch_array() function and use the contents of the fields of each row to construct a further SQL query.

The result of launching this second query is the first set of results that I want.  However, because the number of results produced by doing this is not many I want to make the search less specific by dropping the last record used to make the query.

e.g. the query which produces the first set of results I want could be:

```
 SELECT uid FROM users WHERE (gender=male AND relationship_status=single 
AND shoe_size=10)
```

I would then want to drop the last record so that my query became:

```
SELECT uid FROM users WHERE (gender=male AND relationship_status=single)
```

I have already written code to produce the first query but as I mentioned above I use the mysql_fetch_array function to iterate through ALL of the records.  In subsequent "rounds"  I only want to iterate through successively less records so that my query is less specific.  How can I do this?

This seems like an very inefficient method too - so I'm welcome to any simple ideas which might make it more efficient.

**EDIT:  Thanks for the reply - Yeah I am actually doing this in my program.  I am basically trying to implement a basic search algorithm by taking all the preferences a user has specified in the DB and using it to form a query to look for people with those preferences.  So the first time search using all the criteria, then on successive attempts search using one less criteria and negate the user ids which were previously returned.  At the moment I am constructing the query from scratch for each "round", but I want to find a way I can do this using the last query**

Answer (score 0):

Using the queries above, you could do:

```
SELECT uid 
FROM users 
WHERE uid NOT IN (
        SELECT uid 
        FROM users 
        WHERE 
        (gender=male 
        AND relationship_status=single 
        AND shoe_size=10)
        )
```

This will essentially turn your first query into a sub-query, and use that to negate the results returned. Ie, it will return all the rows, NOT IN the first query.

Comment: Sorry I don't think I explained myself clearly enough - I made an edit.  Thanks for the reply though :D